# PHP display as image

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I am trying to make a PHP page load an image and display, as if it were an image file. Here's what I tried to do:

```
header("Content-type: image/png"); 
echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($ad->location));
```

But this doesn't seems to work. How should this be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to base64 encode image data when outputting it as a file.
Just pass it through.

Comment: This shows symbols like: GIF89a,���5 cM4@ +* )'![! E(O hu'6%',9% � b#4')!�� *WL"-w-�:)$1S++J6%Q$$e">!256/I'62�25<46.� ��%�- �#DBB9FD�04I�T�#

Comment: @Gabriel Bianconi: `GIF89a` is the beginning of a GIF file, not a PNG file. You'll need to send `image/gif` for GIF files, not `image/png`.